# Can we have a Role that has sub roles using identity:

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

Let me explain the scenario: i.e we’ve a role as admin as main role and that ‘admin’ main role has sub roles, sub roles like he can update but not delete or he can view or delete but not create. 
and I want to do all this with asp.net identity roles

I’ve already implemented identity and its working fine with roles but have no clue how to have sub roles to a main role

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to look into the groups and roles, that you are perceiving as roles and sub roles.

Below is the link for Article ASP.NET Identity 2.0: Implementing Group-Based Permissions Management

[ASP.NET Identity 2.0: Implementing Group-Based Permissions Management](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/08/10/ASPNET-Identity-20-Implementing-Group-Based-Permissions-Management.aspx)